Python - Writing data from Firehose lambda to S3 with dynamic names
I am using Amazon Data Firehose with a Lambda function to massage data before writing to S3 destination. I need to change the name of the S3 file written to S3 based on the data processed in the Lambda function.
Is it possible to change the name of the s3 file during execution on Lambda function?

S3 Bucket: Customer-folder
S3 File names based on incoming data. Eg: Smith, Dave, Lori

